# Create event handlers for multiple dynamic controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that creates two dynamic control buttons but I am having difficulty accessing the `.name` property of the dynamic control, which means I can't create the event handler correctly. Due to this problem I am unable to create event handlers. Below shows the code that creates the dynamic controls and also the code that I have written for the event handlers (which isn't functioning correctly)

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cButton As MSForms.CommandButton


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
  If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
     For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value        
        Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        With cButton
            .Name = "CommandButton" & i
            .Left = 150
            .Top = buttonStartPosition
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 140
        End With
     Next i
   End If
End sub

 Private Sub cButton_Click()
    If cButton.Name = "CommandButton1" Then
      MsgBox "Button1"
    ElseIf cButton.Name = "CommandButton2" Then
      MsgBox "Button2"
    End If
 End Sub
```

Once this code is executed and the two buttons are on the screen, I press the first button (`button1`) and nothing happens but when I press the second button (`button2`) I receive the message "Button2". So how come I can't access the first button?

Comment: You only have one cButton variable so the only button that is handled is the last one you create. If you only have a couple of buttons you can use additional `WithEvents` variables, otherwise use a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the events for multiple buttons to work with help from .. [JWalk Excel Tips](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/handle_multiple_userform_buttons_with_one_subroutine/)

Below is the modification based on your code and the link provided.

Create a Class module called "Class1"

[image: Class1 Module]

Add modified code to UserForm1..

```
Option Explicit

Dim Buttons() As New Class1

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer
Dim buttonStartPosition As Integer
Dim cButton As CommandButton

buttonStartPosition = 30

If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
 For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    Set cButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    With cButton
        .Name = "CommandButton" & i
        .Left = 15
        .Top = buttonStartPosition
        .Width = 30
        .Height = 14
    End With

    ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To i)
    Set Buttons(i).ButtonGroup = cButton

    buttonStartPosition = buttonStartPosition + 14

 Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That has done the trick and now I am able to click on both buttons and get their names to come up! I will likely have more questions on this subject but at least i'm a little bit forward

Comment: What if it was two textbox's that I had dynamically created and I wanted to get the values within these textbox's to be output

Comment: @user3538102 .. Posted additional answer to your question and you can add additional events to different objects

Answer (score 1):

@user3538102 .. To your comment regarding Textbox's. Below is example is an example. I added Combo box select either CommandButton or TextBox and generate events. The code works but could be better.

I added combo box to select to dynamically generate object type.

[image: Combo Box]

In UserForm Activate event - Add combo drop down list

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "CommandButton"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "TextBox"
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

In Class1 Class Module ..

[image: ClassModule]

Modified UserForm code ..

```
Option Explicit

Dim cObjs() As New Class1

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer
Dim buttonStartPosition As Integer
Dim cObj As Object

buttonStartPosition = 30

If TextBox1 <> vbNullString Then
 For i = 1 To TextBox1.Value
    If ComboBox1.Value = "CommandButton" Then
        Set cObj = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
    Else
        Set cObj = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    End If

        With cObj
            .Name = ComboBox1.Value & i
            .Left = 15
            .Top = buttonStartPosition
            .Width = 30
            .Height = 14
        End With

    ReDim Preserve cObjs(1 To i)
    If ComboBox1.Value = "CommandButton" Then
        Set cObjs(i).ButtonGroup = cObj
    Else
        Set cObjs(i).TextGroup = cObj
    End If

    buttonStartPosition = buttonStartPosition + 14

 Next i
End If

End Sub
```