# VBA TextBox Array with Events

Tags: vba, events, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of textboxes to handle any amount of data that the user decides to introduce. The problem is, that now I need those textboxes to have a _Change event handler. I have read that you can define controls with events this way:

```
Public WithEvents txt as MSForms.textbox
```

But it doesn't let me define it as an array. Does anyone knows how to do this? Here's my code:

```
Public numacc As Integer
Dim NombreAcc() As MSForms.textbox
Dim k() As MSForms.textbox
Dim Cant() As MSForms.textbox

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If numacc = 0 Then

DatosTuberia.Height = DatosTuberia.Height + 18
Errores.Top = Errores.Top + 18
LblNombre.Visible = True
LblK.Visible = True
LblCantidad.Visible = True

End If

DatosTuberia.Height = DatosTuberia.Height + 18
Errores.Top = Errores.Top + 18

ReDim Preserve NombreAcc(numacc), k(numacc), Cant(numacc)

Set NombreAcc(numacc) = DatosTuberia.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Nombre")
Set k(numacc) = DatosTuberia.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "k")
Set Cant(numacc) = DatosTuberia.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Cantidad")

With NombreAcc(numacc)

.Top = 262 + numacc * 18
.Left = 14
.Width = 76
.Height = 18
.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
.Font.Size = 12

End With

With k(numacc)

.Top = 262 + numacc * 18
.Left = 89.5
.Width = 76
.Height = 18
.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
.Font.Size = 12

End With

With Cant(numacc)

.Top = 262 + numacc * 18
.Left = 164
.Width = 76
.Height = 18
.BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
.Font.Size = 12

End With

numacc = numacc + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: see question [Create Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384623/create-event-handlers-for-multiple-dynamic-controls)

Comment: Why you need create `WithEvents` as  array? You know a name of controls!! Write `if` operator to define from what conrols was message.

Comment: The reason I need the controls with events is that, after the user clicks the "Add textbox" button, I want to call a routine that checks if the content of the dynamically generated textboxes is numeric, so that I can inform the user if there's any error in the content of these textboxes

Comment: You know name of textbox (dynamically create textbox have different  name!!! (see first comment)). Use operator `if` with  condition  name property to determine from what textbox events came from and write different code to different textbox name

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused with your second answer but now I get what you meant. Thank you, actually your first answer solved my problem, I needed all the textboxes to have the same code

Comment: Read answer carefull!